# Can I force the status bar to display as landscape in a portrait view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, statusbar

My view controller is portrait, but I need to change it to landscape.

I want to change the orientation of the status bar to landscape.

Is it possible?

Comment: So you want to see your app in landscape mode only, right?

Comment: Just  curious: Why do you want it?

Comment: @Bhumit : My project is in Portrait, not need to change in to landscape. (its my requirement), I have a textfield in landscape mode. so when I tap on it keyboard comes in portrait . based on status bar orientation keyboard will change.

Comment: @CAN : No. I couldn't get a solution yet.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @TheLivingForce : No